# Can not find file that is in resource folder - java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a question regarding file handling.
I automate a page using selenium, and I need to upload a file in this page.
I want to put the file in resource folder and read it's path in the test (since many OS and path will be different to any computer WIN/MAC).

I put the file manually in the resource folder, and it put it in:

```
X:\Project_11_01_2021\src\test\resources
```

when I used the ClassLoader and try to find the file it not found it,
I saw that if I manually put it in this path it find it, found.

```
X:\Project_11_01_2021\out\test\resources
```

the problem is that I am using git and if I add to the resources it upload to git and every one will get the change, and when I put in  out\test\resources   it is not displayed in the source tree to commit to git.
is their a way that classLoader will search in the first location? and not in the second?

[[image]][path that worked]

[[image]][when here not worked]

/******* test *******/

```
public  void entertax() throws Exception {
    WebDriver deiver2 = getWebDriver();
  
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    String path = classLoader.getResource("TAX12.pdf").getPath();
    System.out.println("\n\n path is  " + path);
    deiver2.switchTo()
            .activeElement();
    deiver2.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"))
    .sendKeys(
            "X:\\Project_11_01_2021\\out\\test\\resources\\fw8TAX12.pdf");



    System.out.println("END");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue looks more like an IDE configuration problem.

Your code `classLoader.getResource("TAX12.pdf")` looks correct (1. using classLoader.getResource() method && 2. specifying the correct relative path within the resources folder).

I assume why the code fails to find the file is due to the fact that the *resources* folder is not part of your applications *classpath* (I'm assuming your trying to run the code from your IDE which apparently seems to be *IntelliJ*).

I'm not regularly using *IntelliJ*, but you can specify the *classpath* settings in the *Module settings*.

In the *Module settings* specify the resources folder as a resource:

[image]

When successfully added the *resources* folder to the classpath it should display an icon like this in the project explorer:

[image]

After adding the *resources* folder to your *classpath* everything should work.

**EDIT:**

In case you're using `Maven` also make sure to specify the resources folder as such in the `pom.xml` file correspondingly.

Also make sure to spell the name of the file you're looking for `"TAX12.pdf"` correctly, since it seems to differ in your code and in your screenshots (not sure if it differs only because posting it here or also in your real code base).